# why I get error when I try to create directive?

Tags: angularjs

I want to create directive:

Here is directive definition:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("siteObjects").directive("myOnOffSwitch", [myOnOffSwitch]);

    function myOnOffSwitch() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                status: "=",
            },
            template:   "<div class='well'>"+
                        "<i class='fa fa-toggle-on active' ng-if='status == true' ng-click='changeStatus();'></i>"+
                        "<i class='fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive' ng-if='status == false' ng-click='changeStatus();'></i>"+

                        "<div style='display: inline-block;font-size: 30px; float:left;' ng-if='status == true'> on</div>" +
                        "<div style='display: inline-block;font-size: 30px; float:left;' ng-if='status == false'>off</div>" +
                        "</div>",

            controller: function ($scope) {

                $scope.changeStatus = function () {
                    $scope.status = !$scope.status;
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Here how I use it in my view:

```
   <my-on-off-switch status="list.status"></my-on-off-switch>
```

I get this error:

```
Error: [$injector:strictdi] function($scope) is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
```

Any idea why I get the error above?

Comment: I would recommend to use `bindToController`, this way you do not have to inject `$scope`, making your code cleaner

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error is coming because the use of strict mode and you are invoking a provider ($scope) which has not been explicitly annotated. To fix it, you could use the $inject property...

```
function myOnOffSwitchController($scope) {
    $scope.changeStatus = function () {
        $scope.status = !$scope.status;
    }
}

myOnOffSwitchController.$inject = ["$scope"];
```

...and them, in your directive:

```
function myOnOffSwitch() {
    return {
        ...
        controller: myOnOffSwitchController
        ...
    }
}
```

See https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/error/$injector/strictdi